# Netbeans is not highlighting unresolved identifiers

Tags: c++, netbeans, highlighting

I've been working with Netbeans on Mac OS for the past few months (in C++) but have now moved to Ubuntu 12.04.  I'm compiling via command line and just using Netbeans as an editor because I like the code assistance and things like that that it has.  Normally it seems people want to disable code assistance and highlighting but in my case, they are not working and I don't know why.  All the boxes are checked under the Editor>Highlighting tab.  When I deliberately misspell a variable it does not complain.  Syntax highlighting works fine.  Is there some other thing I need to install?

I apologize is this is a very simple thing but googling and searching docs has not helped since it seems everyone is concerned with the opposite problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does NetBeans use clang for static code analysis? Maybe you need to install it.

Comment: This would be a very good _comment_, but not good as an answer.